Postman "Get'" returns data and Powershell Invoke-Restmethod does not from Azure DevOps
In a post a couple days ago, it was suggested to me that I use the classificationnodes to get/post to Iterations.  I've been testing those endpoints and if I use the following URL in Postman it works perfectly.
https://dev.azure.com/<org name>/<project name>/_apis/wit/classificationnodes/Iterations?$depth=2&api-version=6.0
But if I use the same URL in Powershell I get null.
$sourceBase64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $UserName, $SourceToken)))
$Header = @{
    Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $SourceBase64AuthInfo)
    Content='application/json'
}
$SourceURL = 'https://dev.azure.com/{0}/{1}/_apis/wit/classificationnodes/Iterations?$depth=2&api-version=6.0' -f $SourceOrg, $SourceProject

Try {
    $SourceIterations = (Invoke-RestMethod $SourceURL -Headers $Header).value
}
Catch {
    if ($_ -match "Access Denied") {
        Throw "Access has been denied, please check your token"
    }
    else {
        Throw $_
    }
}

I can remove the /Iterations and I'll get both Areas and Iterations.  Why does it work in Postman and not in Powershell?
Follow-up question: If I can't use /Iterations, how can I filter the result of the GET to only Iterations (or Areas)?
UPDATE:
It was suggested I look at the headers to see if something additional was added in Postman.  I'm not seeing anything that jumps out at me.


Check the control panel of Postman which has the entire request with all the http headers.  Postman will automatically add headers while powershell does not. Add the missing http headers to your PS script and code should work.

@jdweng I added an update to my question

Add the Authorization, User Agent, Accept-Encoding to your ps request.  They are options in your Invok-RestMethod : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.4

The auth was there, I forgot to include it in the question.  I'll update that.

Powershell doesn't automatically add headers like Postman.  You can get an error like 400 if you do not include User Agent and Accept-Encoding.

The problem ended up being the call to the .value property here:
Try {
    $SourceIterations = (Invoke-RestMethod $SourceURL -Headers $Header).value
}

Once I removed that I got an object back with the child iterations which is what I wanted.
This is the risk of copy/pasting code... :-)

